# How to restore data after MySQL Upgrade?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, windows, upgrade, mysql-5.6

I upgraded from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 by uninstalling 5.5 and then installing MySQL 5.6. Now that MySQL 5.6 is running, none of my DBs or data is present/visible in MySQL Workbench.

I also see that I have two data directories now:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data
```

I've tried various things with no luck. I'd really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You'd probably do batter asking on [dba.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 1):

Open up an Command Line Window as Administrator. Then, follow these steps

## STEP 01 : Shutdown MySQL

```
net stop mysql
```

## STEP 02 : Get the MySQL 5.5 Data into the MySQL 5.6 Data Folder

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"
move data data_empty
mkdir data
cd "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data"
xcopy /s "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\*.*" .
```

## STEP 03 : Upgrade All MySQL 5.5 Files in the MySQL 5.6 Folder

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables
```

## STEP 04: Startup MySQL

```
net start mysql
```

## Review These Steps

## Give it a Try !!!